# Format Specifiers

Tags: ios, nsstring, format-specifiers

I'm wondering about something I saw with format specifiers. What I saw was this:

```
@"%03.1f", someFloat
```

I tested it and it returned in the log

```
"1.5"
```

What is this called, the thing with `03.1` between `%f`?

Comment: Really? Did you search at all? [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) --- **UPDATE** OK, not the best reference, but
[String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) points to [fprintf, printf, snprintf, sprintf - print formatted output](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). You can also read [printf, fprintf, sprintf, snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: The format `"%03.1f"` should create the output `1.5`, not `001.5`.

Comment: Yea, this is not from my code, I wrote it when I created this question. And I thought it worked like this : 3 digits before "." and 1 digit after ".". But I now know how it works :P

Comment: Bookmark the [IEEE printf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html). Objective-C formats use the same exact specifiers (with the addition of `%@` for objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A width (`%3f`) says that we want three digits (positions) reserved for the output.

`%3.1f` -> (print as a floating point at least 3 wide and a precision of 1)

Read [Format Specifiers](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output)

Answer (score 7):

This is a basic question. It is from C language.

A default floating value can be formatted like:

```
%w.pf
```

Here:

**w stands for width**
**p stands for precision**

Please check [C format specifiers](http://www.mobidev.com/shalan/scanf_printf.htm)

Example:

```
Printing 3.141592 using %f       displays 3.141592
Printing 3.141592 using %1.1f    displays 3.1
Printing 3.141592 using %1.2f    displays 3.14
Printing 3.141592 using %3.3f    displays 3.142
Printing 3.141592 using %4.4f    displays 3.1416
Printing 3.141592 using %4.5f    displays 3.14159
Printing 3.141592 using %09.3f   displays 00003.142
Printing 3.141592 using %-09.3f  displays 3.142
Printing 3.141592 using %9.3f    displays     3.142
Printing 3.141592 using %-9.3f   displays 3.142
```

Comment: As complete as your examples are, you should show some examples with no width specified and some with no precision specified. Perhaps an example that shows that the width is ignored if the value is bigger than the width.

Answer (score 5):

**%w.pf**

where

**w -> Minimum width of total value**

**p -> Exact number of decimal after .**

```
float f = 2345.34567;
NSLog(@"%2.2f",f);  //Prints:   "2345.35"
NSLog(@"%.4f",f);   //Prints:   "2345.3556"
NSLog(@"%8.2f",f);  //Prints:   " 2345.35"(includes 1 space to make width of f  '8')
NSLog(@"%15.2f",f); //Prints:   "        2345.35"(includes 8 spaces to make width of f '15')
```